# Draw various symbols with same dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
var shapes = [
    {
        type: 'rect',       // which shape to draw
        size: [ 1, 100 ],   // width and height (for rect) or single number for lines, triangles or squares
        color: color[0],
        orientation: 0      // in degrees in interval [0, 360[
    },
    {
        type: 'triangle',
        size: 55,
        color: color[1],
        orientation: 0
    },
    {
        type: 'triangle',
        size: 96,
        color: color[0],
        orientation: 0
    }
    // etc …
]
```

What I want to do is draw all of the shapes in the dataset, which is of variable length and randomly generated, as defined by the various properties in the different objects defining the shapes. The shapes should be equally distributed and not overlap each other.

The data is bound to a surrounding `g`-element like this:

```
var viewport = d3.select('body').append('svg').selectAll('g').data(shapes)
var group = viewport.append('g')
```

How do I approach this the d3 way? I have tried `shapes.filter(shape => shape.type === 'rect').forEach(/* ... */)` but it feels like I'm not doing it *the d3 way*. Thanks for any clues on how to approach this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with paths, and a function that'd return the path regarding the d.type attribute.

Edit : something a little bit like [that](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MydreG), although you'll have to specify somehow the way you want the symbols to be positioned because with this example, they'll just be drawn on top of each other.

```
var drawers = {
  rect: function(d) {
    return 'M 0 0 l '+ d.size[0] + ' 0 l 0 ' + d.size[1] + ' l -' + d.size[0] + ' 0 l 0 -' + d.size[1];
  },
  triangle: function(d) {},
};

var g = d3.select('#mySvg').append('g');

var symbols = g.selectAll('.symbol')
  .data(shapes);

symbols.enter()
  .append('path')
  .classed('symbol', true)
  .attr({
    d: function(d) {return drawers[d.type](d);}
  });
```

Comment: as for the position: i thought about going with a force directed graph, using the force to equally distribute the options, even though i have never really used anything alike and don't know whether it would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to use the `d3.svg.symbol()` constructor (given that `shapes` is the array as described in the introductory post, with the slight difference of `type` being either `triangle-up`, `circle` or `square`:

```
const center = [ w / 2, h / 2 ]
const vis = d3.select(container)
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h)

const symbols = vis.selectAll('.symbol').data(shapes)

const getPathForShape = d => d3.svg.symbol().type(d.type).size(d.size)()

const paths = symbols.enter()
  .append('path')
  .classed('symbol', true)
  .attr('d', getPathForShape)
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .attr('x', center[0])
  .attr('y', center[1])
```

they were then distributed by using a force directed graph:

```
const force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([w, h])
  .charge(-100)
  .nodes(shapes)
  .gravity(0.1)
  .on('tick', _ => paths.attr('transform', d =>
    'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'))

// simulate a static graph:
force.start()
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) force.tick()
force.stop()
```